# regular expression replace to get legal name

Tags: php, preg-replace

i have list of names with their education qualification  , which i need to cleanup and remove their education qualification . below are some listed example.

1. Berman, PMP, CSM
2. Adesanya, MBA
3. Blagrove-Mandley, MSF
4. Baldwin, M.A. | MBA
5. Akwaboah-CEH,CASP,CAP,CCSK,SCM,VmWare.
6. Arif (CCIE SP)
7. A. Shields, BB, PMP
8. Young chu, CFA

i need the output to be like

- Berman
- Adesanya
- Blagrove-Mandley
- Baldwin
- Akwaboah
- Arif
- A. Shields
- Young chu

i need a valid legal name without qualification. i tried with `preg_replace`. below is my code

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z\. -]/i',' ',$result->last_name);
```

Comment: You need a human, or an advanced AI system.

Comment: Why do `4.` and `5.` not appear in your output? Any reason?

Comment: Try [`'~(?:\s*\([^()]*\)|[,|][^,|\n]+)+$~'`](https://regex101.com/r/qPRd0H/1)

Comment: 4 and 5 also be included , i just output the few example

Comment: Try [`'~(?:-\p{Lu}+\b|\s*\([^()]*\)|[,|][^,|]+)+$~'`](https://regex101.com/r/qPRd0H/3), if your ALLCAPS qualification like `CEF` just consists of several uppercase letters, `\p{Lu}+` should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?:-\p{Lu}+\b|\s*\([^()]*\)|[,|][^,|]+)+$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qPRd0H/3). You may add `u` modifier after the last `~` delimiter to also support Unicode strings.

**Details**

- `(?:-\p{Lu}+\b|\s*\([^()]*\)|[,|][^,|]+)+` - one or more consecutive repetitions of:

  - `-\p{Lu}+\b|` - 1+ uppercase letters as a whole word, or
  - `\s*\([^()]*\)|` - 0+ whitespaces followed with `(`, any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, and then `)`, or
  - `[,|][^,|]+` - a `,` or `|` followed with 1+ chars other than `,` or `|`
- `$` - end of string anchor.